# Convolution power

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, functional-equations

I consider the following equation

$$
m_t = \mu t + \int_{0}^{t} h(t-s)m_sds 
$$

Where $\mu>0$ is fixed and $h$ is a locally integrable and non negative function. I want to solve this equation.

I have a candidate given by

$$
m_t = \mu t + \mu\int_{0}^{t}H(t-s)sds
$$

Where $H(t) = \sum_{n\geq}h^{*n}(t)$ with, for all $n\geq 2$

$$
h^{*n}(t) = \int_{0}^{t} h^{*n-1}(t-u)h(u)du
$$

And $h^{*}(t) = h(t)$.

I get stuck at some point :

Indeed, trying to prove this directly, I get

$$
m_t = \mu t + \mu\int_{0}^{t}(h(t-s) + (H*h)(t-s))sds
$$

**We know that $h(t-s) = h^{*}(t-s)$ and by monotone convergence theorem**

$$
(H*h)(t-s) = \int_{0}^{t}H(t-s-v)h(v)dv = \sum_{n\geq1} \int_{0}^{t}h^{*n}(t-s-v)h(v)dv = \sum_{n\geq1} h^{*n+1}(t-s) = H(t-s)
$$

Thus we get

$$ 
m_t = \mu t + \mu\int_{0}^{t}(h(t-s) +H(t-s))sds 
$$

I doubt that the argument put in bold is right because I cannot see how to conclude using the last expression I wrote. Have you any idea on what could be wrong ? I would like to have some hint rather than answer please, except if all what I did is totally wrong of course.

Thank you a lot !

Comment: Use Laplace transform. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1055410/305862). Classical computation in the so-called "renewal processes".

Comment: Thank you a lot for the link.